In the jetpack's OutlinedTextField, the cursor display centrally problem?
this is my @Composable

@Composable
fun CenteredTextField(
    text: String, onTextChange: (String) -> Unit, modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    val focusRequester = remember { FocusRequester() }
    val keyboardController = LocalSoftwareKeyboardController.current
    val textFieldValue = remember { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue(text)) }

    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        textFieldValue.value = textFieldValue.value.copy(
            selection = TextRange(textFieldValue.value.text.length) // 光标始终在文本末尾
        )

        focusRequester.requestFocus() // 请求焦点
        keyboardController?.show() // 显示软键盘
    }

    Box(
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center, modifier = modifier.fillMaxWidth() // 使Box填满父容器宽度
    ) {
        OutlinedTextField(
            value = textFieldValue.value,
            onValueChange = {
                textFieldValue.value = it
                onTextChange(it.text)
            },
            modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Center) // 确保TextField居中对齐
                .widthIn(min = 100.dp)  // 设置最小宽度，宽度可以随输入内容扩展
                .padding(horizontal = 16.dp).focusRequester(focusRequester), // 给TextField一些水平内边距
            textStyle = TextStyle(textAlign = TextAlign.Center) // 文本居中对齐
        )
    }

}

the frist display,the cursor don't display centrally. you must be input one words.
I know don't use TextFieldValue can solve.
when the echo,i wish the cursor at the end of text.
I need help to slove.
I can't find any way to slove.
